# Adapt navigation for all resolutions

Tags: css, navigation, positioning, resolution

working on website where is img background. I need to position navigation "above the sea" (see screenshot). On my resolution it works fine (1680x1050) but people have navigation "on the sea". I have defined position in percents. Can anybody help me?

```
div#navigation {
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:19.2%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
width: auto;
```

}

SCREEN
My resolution (works fine)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19898988/website.jpg

Friends resolution (works bad)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19898988/1001758_10200668454011660_856480470_n.jpg

web.sundanceparty.sk

Thank you very much

Comment: The site says 'Coming soon...' and asks for authorization. Could you provide an example with non-restricted access?

Comment: sorry, name is admin, password is qwert123

Comment: When you say "all resolutions" does this actually include mobile devices?  Or just all desktops?

Comment: just desktop but I will configure css for mobile too in future

Answer (score 0):

In your current layout, the vertical distance from the page top to the menu bottom is the sum of four parts, two with percentage height (top-margin of #countdown and top-margin of #navigation) and two with fixed height (the heights of the #countdown and the #navigation). This sum makes the slightly different percentage of the page width on different window sizes because the fixed part is not the same percent of different window widths.

To make this percentage constant (and thus making the position of the #navigation *bottom* resolution-independent), I'd suggest to replace the styles of #countdown, #container, and #navigation with the following:

```
#countdown {
  margin-top: 7%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#container {
  font-family: 'Telex',Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 29.9% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#navigation {
  bottom: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So the top offset of the container will always be 29.9% (which seems to correspond the "sea level" on the background image), and the bottom line of the #navigation will always stay at this position.

Comment: Thank you Ilya Streltsyn, you helped me! But now I have another problem, I can't use margin-top:20px; for content. I have defined it but there is no gap between navigation and content and countdown is too high